# Cannot update Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to (2.0) Mono Develop 6.1.4

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

My packages in my project indicated there was a version update to 2.0 for:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- NETStandard.Library
- Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms

The only one I cannot get to update is *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging*

The Error I get is this:

> Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.0.0' does not exist in folder '/home/MyUser/UpdatedPon/pon/sbmanager/packages'
>   Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have been searching the internet the past few days looking for a solution, but I have not found one as of yet.

Has any one ran into this issue, I am running MonoDevelop  6.1.4
and my MONO version is 5.2.0.215.

Lastly this is a WebForms application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.0.0 NuGet packages has assemblies for .NET Standard 2.0.

A more recent version of NuGet is required for .NET Standard 2.0 to be recognised as a target framework. So you would need to use MonoDevelop 7.1 for this to work. Also your project would need to target [.NET 4.6.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) to be able to install the NuGet package.

Alternatively you could try installing the older version Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.1.2 which contains .NET Standard 1.1 assemblies which should be recognised by MonoDevelop 6.1.